# affine and vector-space

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

When I'm working on an affine space, and I consider vectors made up from two affine points, If I work with those vectors then I am working on an affine space or a vector-space?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! A priori, you work in the vector space. Anyway, the pair $(E, A)$ where $E$ is an affine space and $A$ a point of $E$ is isomorphic to the vector space acting on $E$.

Comment: okey, thank you Bernard.